# <ion-checkbox> causes flicker while using it to show/hide a div

Tags: checkbox, ionic-framework, show-hide, angular-ngmodel

I have a scenario where I am using  assigning a model value to it, automatically gets the true false value assigned to it based on whether the check box is checked or not.

```
<ion-checkbox class="checkbox-balanced clear-border" ng-model="DeliveryObj.shippingChecked">Same as billing address</ion-checkbox>
<div class="list list-inset" ng-if="!DeliveryObj.shippingChecked"></div>
```

But when I use that value to show hide a div using ng-if, it causes a flicker, the div appears and then disappears. Any reason why?

I had to go the way around using the display attribute to achieve my final functionality.

**In View as:**

```
 <ion-checkbox class="checkbox-balanced clear-border" ng-change="showShippingDetails(DeliveryObj.shippingChecked)" ng-model="DeliveryObj.shippingChecked"><label>Same as billing address </label></ion-checkbox>
 <div class="list list-inset" id="shippingDetails" hidden></div>
```

**In controller as:**

```
// Functionality            : Shows/hides the shipping address div
// Params                   : showDetails - true/false 
$scope.showShippingDetails  = function(showDetails){

   if(showDetails){
         // $("#shippingDetails").hide();
         document.getElementById("shippingDetails").style.display = "none";
   }
   else{
         // $("#shippingDetails").show();
         document.getElementById("shippingDetails").style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the difference between the two solution is that `ng-if` is changing the dom tree. So, maybe it would appear different, especially when your list is very long.

Try to use `ng-show` to do it again, `ng-show` only change the style for visiblity but not deleting or adding elements to the dom tree.

Comment: It worked well for chrome though but had issues in android and ios, ng-hide worked, but still wondering why the flicker caused, while trying to add element to dom, why was the model value toggling? Any idea?

Comment: is it possible that before your boolean variable become true first? I mean some kind of default value in your application somewhere. If you really worry about this, maybe you should build a codepen to recreate it in a clean situation, so people can help you to debug it.

Comment: Well, it works fine without any issues in desktop browser but detected in android and iphone browsers, so i don't think codepen/fiddle will be able to reproduce it. :(

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to use `ng-cloak`, as per the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak):

> The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template
>   from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled)
>   form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid
>   the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.